# unable to get external css working in a dynamic web project spring

Tags: css, spring-mvc

Am currently working on a spring mvc project on Eclipse. Am unable to get an external css working in a .jsp . My folder structure is as follows

Myproj, WebContent,
   WEB-INF,
      css, 
          .css files

I use the following piece of code to reference the css file.

```
<link href="<c:url value="/css/filename.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I use spring jars version 3.1.0. I have also added the following lines of code within myproj-servlet.xml

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<mvc:resources location="../css/" mapping="/css/**"/>
```

Still am unable to access my css file or get it apply to my jsp file. While using firebug i see that the css link gets a 404 not found only. Where could be the issue/ how can i resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your resource location to

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/css/" mapping="/css/**"/>
```

and while accessing on jsp you could very well write

```
<c:set var="context" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${context}/css/style.css" />
```

Cheers.